# Mensagem Toast No centro da activity no Android

Tags: android, toasts

Estou criando um aplicativo e quero colocar uma mensagem usando o Toast. Mas ao criar o toast o mesmo só fica na parte de baixo da activity. Para centralizar a mensagem tentei usar esta linha de comando.

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tarefa salva com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            Toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,0,0, null);
            Toast.show();
```

Estou usando a última versão do android studio(3.2)

mas não está dando este erro

```
error: method setGravity in class Toast cannot be applied to given types;
required: int,int,int
found: int,int,int,<null>
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Answer (score 2):

Você está iniciando o Toast 3 vezes fazendo dessa forma.

Para que funcione, você deve fazer assim:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tarefa salva com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

Onde ele cria apenas um.